# How to display value of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to  display  all the cheked values of a chekbox, this is my attempt:

```
<p>jQuery is :</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="s" name="super"> Super !<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="g" name="genial"> Génial<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="j" name="joli"> Joli<br>
 <input type="button" value="display" id="disp">
 <script>
$('#disp').click(function(data){
$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked");
alert($("this").val());
});
 </script>
```

Comment: What result did you get using the above codes?? Did any errors come up in the console??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you could try a *little* bit harder to solve this on your own, no?

Regardless, your checkboxes don't have value attributes defined: `name` & `value` are different [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

`$('this')` would try to make a collection of `<this>` elements, and `$(this)` would refer to the button in that event handler.

You're looking for something along these lines:

http://jsbin.com/luyaweqaqe/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="super"> Super !<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="genial"> Génial<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="joli"> Joli<br>

<button id="bt">Check</button>
```

JS

```
$('#bt').on('click', function () {
  var arr = [];

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  });

  alert(arr);
});
```

Here's some reading material:

- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [HTML Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Answer (score 1):

It cannot get the value with .val because there is no value. Try something like this:

```
<p>jQuery is :</p>
<input class="box" type="checkbox" value="Super">Super</br>
<input class="box" type="checkbox" value="Génial">Génial</br>
<input class="box" type="checkbox" value="Joli">Joli</br>
<input type="button" value="display" id="disp">



$('#disp').click(function () {
    $(".box:checked").each(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ms14eLz0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this. You do not need `data` in your function as your not passing anything in it. What this should do is find all the boxes which are checked and then loop through them and add them to the array. Then alert it at the end.

```
 $('#disp').click(function () {
      var array = [];
    $(".box:checked").each(function () {
        array.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(array + ' checked');
});
```

Comment: I had this result `undefined on on on` , it didn't work

Comment: try this mark this works now sorry had a mistake in my function @mak_doni